# Why are mutable references inconsistent between impl and normal functions?

Tags: rust, types, reference, mutable-reference

For functions in an impl block we use this syntax:

```
fn test(&mut self) {}
```

But for a normal function we use this syntax:

```
fn test(data: &mut u64) {}
```

I understand `self` is a variable, while `Self` is type. In first case we use `&mut` with the variable (`self`), but in the second then we used `&mut` with the type (`u64`). Why is there this inconsistency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The presence of `self` as the first parameter of an associated function has [special meaning](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#methods), and has special shorthand syntax:

- `self` is short for `self: Self`
- `&self` is short for `self: &Self`
- `&mut self` is short for `self: &mut Self`

So you can see that the `mut` in `&mut self` is part of its type; `self` is a mutable reference.

---

For completeness, you may also see a lone `mut` *before* the parameter name and type. This would mean the *variable* can be mutated and rebound, but does not affect the type. This is the same distinction as `let` vs `let mut`. i.e. `mut data: &u64` would mean the `u64` being referenced cannot be modified, but the variable `data` can be re-assigned to reference a different `u64`.